# How does sizeof(struct) help provide ABI compatibility?

Tags: c, api, compatibility, abi

Suppose a C library has to share the details of a structure with the application code and has to maintain API and ABI backward compatibility. It tries to do this by checking the size of the structure passed to it.

Say, the following structure needs to be updated. In library version 1,

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    char* x;
    int y;
} foo;
```

In version 2 of the library, it is updated to:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    char* x;
    int y;
    int z;
} foo_2;
```

Now, library version 2 wants to check if the application is passing the new `foo_2` or the old `foo` as an argument, `arg`, to a function. It assumes that the application has set `arg.size` to `sizeof(foo)` or `sizeof(foo_2)` and attempts to figure out whether the application code groks version 2.

```
if(arg.size == sizeof(foo_2)) {
    // The application groks version 2 of the library. So, arg.z is valid. 
} else {
    // The application uses of version 1 of the library. arg.z is not valid.
}
```

I'm wondering why this won't fail. On GCC 4.6.3, with -O3 flag, both `sizeof(foo)` and `sizeof(foo_2)` are 24. So, won't v2 library code fail to understand if the application is passing a struct of type `foo` or `foo_2`? If yes, how come this approach seems to have been used?

http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/dec/coding-for-coders-api-and-abi-considerations-in-an-evolving-code-base/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/12/56061.aspx

---

Follow on question: Is there a good reason to favor the use of `sizeof(struct)` for version discrimination? As pointed out in the comments, why not use an explicit `version` member in the shared struct?

Comment: Where are you getting 24 from ?

Comment: This probably won't work. `sizeof` is a compile-time thing, and you want to check the size at *runtime*.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Hm, what? We wat to know which version of the struct the caller used, not the callee, so it looks good from that direction. Still, spiky is right that on most 64-bit platforms, the pointer is 8 byte aligned and sized, the int 4, and thus there is no size-difference between the two structs.

Comment: This of course *could* fail, it does in 64-bit code.  But it is not like you are not going to find this out *quickly* when you test.  So you come up with something else, like making it a *long* instead.

Comment: this is why it's not uncommon to see reserved members in the second version of the struct, by padding the struct they ensure the `sizeof` is different

Comment: Why to store size and not the library version? If you put somewhere value 1 for library version 1 and 2 for version 2, you will have no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match your observations, I posit

- `char*` has size 8 and alignment 8.
- `int` has size 4 and alignment 4.
- Your implementation uses optimal packing.

You are quite right that in that case, both your old and new structure would have the same size, and as your version-discriminator is the structures size, the upgrade is an ABI-breaking change. (Few logic-errors are also syntax-errors, and the former are not diagnosed by a compiler).

Only changes to the structure which result in a bigger size, with the new struct containing all the fields of the old one at the same offsets, can be ABI-compatible under that scheme: Add some dummy variables.

---

There is one possibility which might save the day though:

- If a field contains a value which was previously invalid, that might indicate that anything else might have to be interpreted differencty.

Comment: the proper solution is to pad v2 of the struct so it doesn't have the same `sizeof`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of an intermediate structure.
For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int           version;
    void*         data;
} foo_interface;

typedef struct
{
    char*         x;
    int           y;
} foo;

typedef struct
{
    char*         x;
    int           y;
    int           z;
} foo_2;
```

In my library version 2, I would export by name the following function:

```
foo_interface* getFooObject()
{
    foo_interface* objectWrapper = malloc(sizeof(foo_interface));
    foo_2* realObject = malloc(sizeof(foo_2));

    /* Fill foo_2 with random data... */
    realObject.x = malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
    realObject.y = 2;
    realObject.z = 3;

    /* Fill our interface. */
    objectWrapper.version = 2; /* Here we specify version 2. */
    objectWrapper.data = (void*)realObject;

    /* Return our wrapped data. */
    return (objectWrapper);
}
```

Then in the main application I would do:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    /* Load library + Retrieve getFooObject() function here. */

    foo_interface* objectWrapper = myLibrary.getFooObject();

    switch (objectWrapper->version)
    {
        case 1:
            foo*   realObject = (foo*)(objectWrapper ->data);
            /* Do something with foo here. */
            break;
        case 2:
            foo_2* realObject = (foo_2*)(objectWrapper ->data);
            /* Do something with foo_2 here. */
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown foo version!");
            break;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

---

*As usual, security checks (when allocating memory for example) are not included for readability of the code.*

*Also, I would use **[stdint.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)** to ensure data types binary compatibility (to be sure the sizes of `int`, `double`, `char*` and so on are the same across different architectures). For example, instead of `int` I would use `int32_t`.*

Comment: APR? Just use stdint.h

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this scheme to distinguish different versions of your API you simply have to make sure that the different struct versions have different sizes.

To do so, you can either try to make `foo` smaller by forcing the compiler to use tighter packing, or you can make `foo_2` larger by adding additional (unused) fields.

In any way, you should add an assertion (preferably at compile time) for `sizeof(foo) != sizeof(foo_2)` to make sure the structs always actually have different sizes.